# Simple read/display C program outputs incorrect value while user inputs data

Tags: c, scanf

Can someone run the following C program on your IDE and advise me what I am missing?.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

int main()
{

    int a;
    char s;
    char n[10];

    printf("What is your name?: ");
    scanf("%s", &n);

    printf("What is your age?: ");
    scanf("%d", &a);

    printf("Are you male or female?: ");
    scanf("%c", &s);

    printf("Your name is %s\nYour age is %d\nYour sex is %c\n", n, a, s);

    getch();
    return 0;

}
```

While we enter the age and hit the enter button, it slips and shows wrong output without evening asking for the third input "Are you male or female?". I tested it on Turbo C++, Dev C++, Code Blocks, all show the same error output.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Second scanf is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4023643/second-scanf-is-not-working)

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that the `scanf("%c", &s);` takes the new-line character. Maybe you could try the following `scanf(" %c", &s);` (important ist the white-space before `%c`) as described here [Problems with character input using scanf()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13710867/problems-with-character-input-using-scanf) or [How to do scanf for single char in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13542055/how-to-do-scanf-for-single-char-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

It would be correctly to write

```
printf("What is your name?: ");
scanf("%s", n);
           ^^^
```

or even

```
printf("What is your name?: ");
scanf("%9s", n);
```

instead of

```
printf("What is your name?: ");
scanf("%s", &n);
```

and

```
printf("Are you male or female?: ");
scanf(" %c", &s);
      ^^^
```

instead of

```
printf("Are you male or female?: ");
scanf("%c", &s);
```

Otherwise in the last case a white space character is read into the variable `s`.